# How to check if database and connection to it is working well with hikaripool or quill?

Tags: scala, hikaricp, quill

I am working with stack: scala, hikari-pool, quill, postgres. Are there any build-in instruments in hikari-pool/quill to check if connection is valid and database is ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `hikaricp.connectionTestQuery` property in the HikariCP config to `"SELECT 1"`.